# Member function SFINAE with alias templates in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae

To shorten the amount repeated usage of a particular `std::enable_if` type used within a class to toggle a function's presence based on the class template's type matching a specific type, I used an alias template declaration. A minimal example of my general setup is as follows:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class A final {};

template<typename T>
class B final {
public:
  template<typename U, typename V>
  using check = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, V>>;

  template<typename U = T>
  check<U, A> foo();
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
typename B<T>::template check<U, A> B<T>::foo() {

}

int main() {
  B<A> b;

  b.foo();
}
```

While this appears to work fine in Clang 7.0.0 as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4LOWvRysJ4boMcom), Visual Studio 15.5.7 on the other hand (using `/std:c++17`) fails to compile with the following error message:

```
main.cpp(17): error C2244: 'B<T>::foo': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
main.cpp(17): note: see declaration of 'B<T>::foo'
main.cpp(17): note: definition
main.cpp(17): note: 'B<T>::check<U,A> B<T>::foo(void)'
main.cpp(17): note: existing declarations
main.cpp(17): note: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type B<T>::foo(void)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
```

Is this a problem with the Visual Studio compiler's implementation of various features required for SFINAE to work properly or is there something wrong with using an alias template in this way? It should also be noted that replacing the alias entirely with the full `std::enable_if` type does solve this issue, but I am more curious as to why this is and if there is some way it can be done to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I think I saw a similar problem with MSVC in a stack overflow question before. Someone suggested the following : https://godbolt.org/g/vpnP6r (besides, it even gets rid of the annoying `typename B<T>::template`)

Comment: I found the question I was thinking about, the problem is slightly different though [Keyword 'template' confuses MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814193/keyword-template-confuses-msvc).

Comment: @Caninonos Thanks, that seems to be the problem and the solution suggested does appear to work.