# Compile error when building fbxsdk headers in visual studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, fbx

I tried to build both 2015 and 2018 versions of fbxsdk headers with visual studios but get error:

> c:\program files\autodesk\fbx\fbx sdk\2018.0\include\fbxsdk\core\fbxproperty.h(1161): error C2903: 'GetPropertyValue': symbol is neither a class template nor a function template

the error occurs at this piece of code:

```
        T EvaluateValue(const FbxTime& pTime=FBXSDK_TIME_INFINITE, bool pForceEval=false)
    {
        return GetAnimationEvaluator()-> template GetPropertyValue<T>(*this, pTime, pForceEval);
    }
```

which is inside a template class, the linux version of the headers are equal but produce no error, and I even tried mingw g++ and compiles with no error (but can’t link due to dll not being made with g++).

What is that piece of code even doing? Creating a template and returning it as value?

I removed the template keyword from the function and it started compiling in visual studios (and g++ started giving errors), does that changes the result?

Could this error be caused because of me using visual studios 2017 instead of 2015 recommended by the fbxsdk library? Other than that I did everything they recommended in here: https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2018/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_getting_started_installing_and_configuring_configuring_the_fbx_sdk_for_wind_html

I installed the library from: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=26416244

Comment: I've seen something like this in another question a few days ago, I think it was described as a bug. I hope I can find it.

Comment: Also, I think that placing code in a c/c++ header file is a bad programing practice. I am no c++ expert (more of a c/Haskell guy), but isn’t it possible to place only the c++’s functions and classes declaration in the header file and the implementation in the cpp files?

Comment: Not sure if related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814193/keyword-template-confuses-msvc  Who is right? GCC and Clang or MSVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just encountered the same error. The solution was to switch Conformance mode to NO in Configuration Properties/ C/C++/ Language. I'm not sure if this will cause any problems down the road, but it did the job for now.

Comment: You are right, that does solve the problem for the MS VS editor, and I also found that compiling using the command line tool (cl) to be another solution, most likely the conformance mode is an argument used by the editor to call the cl compiler. A quick internet search shows that Conformance mode yes is now a default in newer MS VS version, maybe telling autodesk would be a good idea for them to update their install instructions, but they disable their free support email and their forums are too slow.