# Compile errors when building a project using fbx SDK in Visual Studio/C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, fbx

I am trying to build a project about loading fbx objects in OpenGL. I used this resource's codes: https://github.com/sho3la/FBX-Loader-OpenGL-C-

But I got these compile errors:
'GetCacheChannel': is not a member of 'fbxsdk::FbxVertexCacheDeformer'
'IsActive': is not a member of 'fbxsdk::FbxVertexCacheDeformer'
'lHasVertexCache': an object of const-qualified type must be initialized
'SetActive': is not a member of 'fbxsdk::FbxVertexCacheDeformer'

I have also seen [Compile error when building fbxsdk headers in visual studios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186336/compile-error-when-building-fbxsdk-headers-in-visual-studios) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30456 and done their suggestions, but still, there are not any changes in these errors.

Comment: Autodesk FBX tends to change a lot. Which version of the Autodesk FBX does that code expect you to use?

Comment: I used the last version of it. Its link is https://damassets.autodesk.net/content/dam/autodesk/www/adn/fbx/2020-1-1/fbx202011_fbxsdk_vs2017_win.exe

Comment: But what version does the code you used build with? That project is six years old so I'm guessing a really old one.

Comment: I created a new project in visual studio 2019, and just used that link's c++ codes.

Comment: The source code in the GitHub project you are using is probably written for Autodesk FBX SDK 2013 or 2014 version.  That far back they only provided VS 2012 versions of their library, so you need to *modify* the code to build with the latest versions. See [FBX SDK Archive](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-archives). The oldest one you can use is 2016.1.2 because the VS 2015 libraries are binary compatible with VS 2019 per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoDesk has changed its libraries. Therefore for using these functions in those errors, instead of using FBX SDK 2020, I used FBX SDK 2014.2.1 VS2012, and it works for me.